# 3rd Fragment override 1st on backPress, when don't use addToBackStack in 2nd fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I open `fragments` like this: [1]+with `addToBackStack`) > [2](without `addToBackStack`) > [3]

in `Fragment 3` when click `onBackPress` Button then `2nd` is not visible but `3rd` override `1`.
[image]

**If I use `addToBackStack` in `2nd fragment` also, then everything is fine(No override issue).**

> But  I have to hide `2nd fragment` when user visit `3rd fragment` and
> direct come back to `1st fragment`.

here is my code:

open `root fragment`**[1]** from `activity` with `fragmentTransaction.add`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.abbcHomeFragmentContainer, new FragmentHomeAbbc(), null);
    //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**[1](with `addToBackStack`) >[2]** :opening `2nd fragment`

```
FragmentListOfBankAbbc fragment= new FragmentListOfBankAbbc();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    if (getActivity()!=null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.abbcHomeFragmentContainer, fragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong (#201)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**[2](without `addToBackStack`) > [3]**

```
private void  funOpenFragments(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle){
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    if (getActivity()!=null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.abbcHomeFragmentContainer, fragment, null);
        //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong (#202)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Now open `3rd fragment` and click showing 3rd fragment+1st fragment.

Comment: Can you please try rephrasing your question? It is unclear what behavior you do not want during onBackPressed() in the cases of (a) adding 2nd fragment w/o addToBackstack and (b) adding 2nd fragment with addToBackstack

Comment: when user goto [3rd fragment] , then on backpress user will see [1st fragment] not [2nd]. So, Now error is [3rd fragment]'s content showing on [1st fragment] mean override. I dont want override.

Comment: You can try to override `onBackPressed` of your 3rd fragment to safely remove the 3rd and 2nd fragments and go to the 1st fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user go **[1] > [2] > [3]**

Then `onBackPress` user will be **[3] > [1]**.

> Finally, I got Solution.
>
> > follow these 2 steps inside **[2nd] fragment:**
>
> **Step1.** Just add `fragmentManager.popBackStack();` before `fragmentTransaction` mean calling `[3] fragment`. *(after this line,
> It destroy/pop 2nd fragment and open 1st fragment again before open
> 3rd fragment. It mean when users press back button on 3rd fragment.
> then in recent fragment, there is 1st fragment not 2nd)*
> **Step2.** add `.addToBackStack(null)` also with `fragmentTransaction`

[image]

**[2] Fragment** : here on button click we will open `3rd fragment` .

```
if (getActivity()!=null){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    //this popBackStack will close this [2]fragment.
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(); //<<<<<<<just add this before "fragmentTransaction".

    //now open [3]fragment here, Now in recent fragment is only [1]fragment not [2].
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.abbcHomeFragmentContainer, fragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //<<<<<<<<<add this also
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

} else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong (#202)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**(^_^) Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    loadFragment(FirstFragment())    // add this line
}


private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
    fragmentManager.popBackStack()
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

FirstFragment.kt

```
 binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener {
        val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.frameLayout, SecondFragment(), getString(R.string.fragment_tag_title_second_fragment))
        fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack("Second")
        fragmentTransaction?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
```

SecondFragment.kt

```
private fun onClick() {
    binding.apply {
        btnNext.setOnClickListener { loadFragment(ThirdFragment()) }
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener {   activity?.onBackPressed() }
    }
}

private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment,getString(R.string.fragment_tag_title_third_fragment))
    fragmentTransaction?.addToBackStack("third")
    fragmentTransaction?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

ThirdFragment.kt

```
 private fun onClick() {
    binding.apply {
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```